# All timer jobs are missing from a Web Application

Tags: timer-jobs, web-application

A timer job solution has been written and installed to our farm. It appeared to install correctly.

However when you go to Central Admin under timer jobs and look at `http://CentralAdmin/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx` for the Web Application we deployed the solution to, all the timer jobs happen to be missing.

Has anyone else had this problem and how do we fix it without having to delete the web application and restore all the databases again.

Comment: How is the TimerJob registered to the WebApplication? If in feature receiver is that feature activated?

Comment: You can see other timer jobs right?

Comment: Sounds like something drastic needs to happen, I think restoring may be the only option. Might be worth trying to add another application server to the mix to see if it sets up the timer jobs for the web app perhaps?

Comment: The timerjob is activated by a feature. It is active. You cannot see any other timer job at all. According to the logs and history job files, no timer jobs are running.

Comment: In the end we have recreated the web application and restored all the databases. Luckly this all happened on our build server. Very concerned that this will happen again on our live server, so still hoping someone will know an answer why this is happening, and how to fix it without restore.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue in all our SP2016 environments. We caught it when the Alerts for all lists stopped, which is handled by the Immediate Alerts job. Running the following PS script worked for us - the missing standard scheduled tasks were restored.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm

$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()

$w = Get-SPWebApplication https://[your web application address]

$w.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```